# DNS: zone ns.test/IN: not loaded due to errors

Tags: dns

Here is the syslog:

```
Dec  5 13:24:49 osboxes named[3436]: zone ns.test/IN: NS 'a.ns.test' has no address records (A or AAAA)
Dec  5 13:24:49 osboxes named[3436]: zone ns.test/IN: not loaded due to errors.
Dec  5 13:24:49 osboxes named[3436]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Dec  5 13:24:49 osboxes named[3436]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Dec  5 13:24:49 osboxes named[3436]: all zones loaded
Dec  5 13:24:49 osboxes named[3436]: running
```

Here is the file used in the configuration (db.linux.rocks):

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     a.ns.test. bruno.localhost. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
; Bellow are A record adresses
;
@               IN      NS      a.ns.test.
@               IN      AAAA    ::1
testmoodle      IN      A       192.168.141.130
www             IN      A       192.168.141.130
a.ns.test               IN      A       192.168.141.130
```

It's my first time setting up a DNS server.
I have tried to add "ns.test IN A 192.168.141.130".
When i ping it says "unknown host...".
The dig command returns this:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;a.ns.test.         IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           5   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2015120500 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 87 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
```

If there's anything missing out let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have an IP poiting directly to my own DNS server.